# Accessing members of a set by one of their properties

Tags: c++, collections

I often find myself in the situation where an object contains a set of objects, and I want to access one of these objects based on one of its properties.

How I currently do this in C++ is to put those objects in a map, where the key is a copy of the object's property. For example:

```
map.insert(make_pair(obj.getName(), obj));
```

However, this does not seem right to me, because I do not define a mapping - the relation between the property and the object is already defined.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I believe [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is the straightforward way of doing this, especially if your C++ is modern enough to support lambdas.

Comment: Ah, the fantastic algorithms library I keep forgetting about! I expect this to be much slower than my approach for large sets. Usually this will not be a problem though, as the sets do not tend to be very large.

Comment: If it is only by one specific property then how about defining operator< based on that property? I admit it's a bit of a hack, but if it works...

Comment: Or just use `std::set` with a custom comparator to avoid the duplication. Downside - `set.find` requires an instance for lookup.

Comment: I can see the concern; you don't want `object.id` to exist twice in code; you'd run the risk of its id falling out of sync. But, this is certainly what `map`s are good for. If `id` can change, I would go for `find_if` until performance is a genuine concern (NOT always the case). Otherwise, I'd use the `map`, and keep its access modifier limited.

Comment: @Useless yes, I had considered this - should have mentioned that in the question. I could hide the creation of this object in the `getChildByName` method on the 'parent'. I doubt this is a good solution in most cases though, depending on the type of object.

Comment: @Katana314 this is indeed a concern, though if the `id` can change, I foresee more problems: if I change the id of one object in the set to be the same as the id of another object in the set, they are not unique anymore. Also, I expect that the ordering would get messed up, because the set doesn't know its contents have changed. Whether these are problems depends on the precise container, of course.

Comment: @Katana314 also, what do you mean with "keep its access modifier limited"? Make it private and only allow access to its members via methods such as `getChildById`?

Comment: @Oebele It definitely gets harder if this type can be accessed with no relationship to the collection; in some cases, that might make it worth maintaining a relationship to its owned collection (and, eg, throwing an exception if the ID exists). You were correct with your interepretation of "keep access limited".

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues.

1. What is the mapping?
2. Can the mapping change?

First, do not worry about the mapping already being defined. As long as the name is the identity of the object (think primary key in a relational database), then it is a *natural key* and absolutely should be used as a handle to your object. You are not "defining" anything, you are simply using a property of your object.

The other issue is whether or not your key is immutable, and an immutable property of the object.

With C++, the name in the key and in the object will be separate objects "owned" by their respective containers (the map, and the object). A C++ string is mutable. Furthermore, if the name can be set to a new string on the object, that is another possible change.

I think if you make the key `const`, and the name `const` on the object, then you mitigate the concern that they may get out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to share an approach that worked for me in the past:

```
struct Thing {
  std::string const property; // This is an important assumption
  int dummy;
};
```

I want to reference the `property` of things, so I use [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper). Assuming that lookup happens a lot more often than changing the things, I would store the things in a `std::vector`. In order to achieve fast lookup I'd use a map from references to the properties to references to the things.

```
std::vector<Thing> things;
std::map<
  std::reference_wrapper<std::string const>,
  std::reference_wrapper<Thing>> lookup;
```

Doing a lookup is simple, given a string `p`:

```
Thing & i_want = lookup.at(p).get();
```

Inserting things needs to take care of possibly invalidated references:

```
// Thing newcomer
auto old_capacity = things.capacity();
things.push_back(newcomer); // or emplace
if (old_capacity == things.capacity()) {
  lookup.emplace(
    std::ref(things.back().property),
    std::ref(things.back()));
} else {
  lookup.clear();
  for (auto const & t : things) {
    lookup.emplace(
      std::ref(t.property), std::ref(t));
  }
}
```

Removing things is left as an exercise to the reader. Using a different data structure than a vector as backing storage can be preferable if addition or removal of things happens more often.

*Note that the code above is only a rough sketch of the idea. I'm on my mobile phone atm where it's rather hard to write that down and actually test it.*

Comment: Suggestion: use a `std::deque<>` as backing storage instead of a vector. References to elements in a deque are stable as long as insertions and deletions happen at either end only, so `push_back()` is safe. Therefore you don't need the if-test and else-branch.